# inheritance and passing parameters

Tags: c#, oop

Lets say i have class Parent

```
       public class Parent
       {
         //several properties... P1,P2..etc
       }
```

Another class

```
      public class Child:Parent
      {
       //several new properties C1,C2..etc
      }
```

Is it possible to write a function that can accept either parent or child for type A ?

```
     private void DoSomething( Child/Parent A, bool IsParent) 
     {
      //process additional child properties if IsParent is false
     }
```

Comment: Can you move the logic inside of the Parent and Child classes?

Comment: The logic is neither inside the parent nor in the child class..its in another class...that does the processing...

Answer (score 5):

Due to inheritance, a parameter of type `Parent` will *always* accept a object of type `Child`.

The bigger problem is actually `IsParent`. Without checking that your are *not* any of the child types, that would be impossible to determine. Because base types shouldn't know about their derivations, you wouldn't do that anyways.

More likely; you would make `DoSomething` **`virtual`** so you could have a different implementation in each derived class.

Answer (score 3):

You can overload it.

```
void DoSomething(Child child)
{
   DoSomething((Parent) child);
   //process child specific logic
}

void DoSomething(Parent parent)
{
   //process parent
}
```

Depending on your code, you may not even need the bool `IsParent`.

If you just have a *base* instance, but need to work with it if it is a `Child` instance, you can check in code and handle extra logic.

```
void DoSomething(Parent parent)
{
    var child = parent as Child;
    if (child != null)
        DoSomethingForChild(child);
}

void DoSomethingForChild(Child child)
{
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the caller already has compile-time knowledge of the type. Which I guess is true if the caller could have passed a flag, but it's not really any better a design than the code in the original question (which wasn't that great to start with).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree. I have updated my answer with a different version to handle that case.

Answer (score 2):

Sure...

```
 private void DoSomething(Parent parent) 
 {
    if (parent is Child)
    {
        var child = parent as Child;
        // do something with child here
    }
 }
```

Here's an example of a simple usage:

```
public class Parent { public string Name { get; set; } }

public class Child : Parent { public Parent Parent { get; set; } }

public static void Introduce(Parent p)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, my name is: {0}", p.Name);

    if (p is Child)
    {
        Child c = p as Child;
        Console.WriteLine(" - and my parent's name is: {0}", c.Parent.Name);
    }
}

private static void GenericTester()
{
    Parent p = new Parent {Name = "Dad"};
    Child c = new Child {Name = "Son", Parent = p};

    Introduce(p);
    Introduce(c);
}

// Ouput:
// Hello, my name is: Dad
// Hello, my name is: Son
//  - and my parent's name is: Dad
```

Comment: You should *not* do this from within the `Parent` class though; parent's shouldn't know about their children.

Comment: Good answer, except that following an `is` with an `as` is pointless. Just do the `as` and check the result for `null`: `child = parent as Child; if (child != null) ...` (And as noted elsewhere, polymorphism is a preferred approach over this kind of explicit type-checking)

Comment: i thought we cannot assign a type of parent to a type of child ...Is that not what we are doing here ??

Comment: @Habib it works fine. Let me update with a sample you can copy/paste to test it out.

Comment: @RufusL, no need for sample, I have no idea what I was thinking. +1

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm aware of the `as` check, but not sure why that is preferable. Is there some benefit to doing `var x = y as z; if (x != null)...` over `if (y is z) var x = y as z;`? In both cases you're doing the same assignment, and in both cases you're doing a quick reference check. What is the difference?

Comment: @RufusL: `is` and `as` have similar run-time type-checking overhead, while a comparison against `null` is a simple value comparison. As with most performance-related issues, most of the time the extra overhead is irrelevant. But IMHO it's better to be in the habit of avoiding it, since it's just as easy to as it is to not.

Answer (score 2):

When you use inheritance the name already says that you inherit from another type. If you create a Class `Child` that inherits from class `Parent` and you have the following method

```
public Method(Parent obj)
```

That means it accepts a `Parent` class **and** also **all** inherited types. Thus you can call your method with an `Parent` or a `Child` Object.

But in my opinion you should rethink of using inheritance. It is in my opinion an overused pattern often lead to bad code. For example every Person is always a `Child` but not every Person is a `Parent`. But every Person can become a `Parent`, but the he is automatically a `Parent` **and** a `Child`. Thus your way how you think in your code doesn't resemble reality.

Actually Code don't must resemble reality, but you should try to be as flexible as possible. If not it is very likely that you later run into problems implementing new functionality. And, from my experience, that will happen sooner or later.

Instead you should think more in `Behaviours`. What should a `Parent` do, which functionality has a `Child`? You should think about that and instead write an interface that resembles this behaviour.

For example when both have a name you should write.

```
interface INameable {
    string Name { get; }
}
```

what you then do is create your classes like this.

```
class Parent : INameable { ... }
class Child : INameable { ... }
```

The difference is that you create multiple interfaces that resemble different behaviours. If you for example want to write a method that only needs an object that has a `Name` Attribute you just can write.

```
Method(INameable obj)
```

Why is that better? You also can write classes that you probably never would inherit from `Parent` or `Child` but that still has a Name and would be valid for that method. For example.

```
class Car : INameable { ... }
class Dog : INameable { ... }
...
```

You also should note that a class can have multiple Interfaces not just on.

To reduce multiple implementation you also should use **Composition over Inheritance**. So instead of achieving Code Reuse through inheritance you should use other objects to create bigger classes. These often leads to smaller classes, that are more separated and easier to maintain. You will also see that you often have a lot better code reuse and don't end in the *inheritance hell* how i would call it.

Answer (score 1):

The first question I would ask -- is there an association between these two objects in such as way that the complexity can be reduced by using basic object oriented principals?

If so, you could create an interface that both Child and Parent classes must implement, e.g.

```
interface IParent
{
   string Name {get; set;}
   string Age {get; set;}
}

class Child
{
   Parent Parent {get; set;}
}

class Parent
{
   IEnumerable<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

...

class Parent : IPerson
class Child : IPerson
```

...and then have your method accept an *IPerson* e.g.

```
void DoSomething(IPerson person)
{
   if(person is Child)
   {
      var child = person as Child;
   } 
   else if (person is Parent)
   {
      var parent = person as Parent;
   }
}
```

The question you have to ask though is, *does this make sense in your context?*

Without knowing the details, many of the more simple approaches, such as overloading, are as good as any approach to solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass `Child` as well as `Parent` objects when you specify the parameter as `Parent`.

You will need to cast if you want to access `Child` specific properties though and nobody can guarantee that it's actually either `Child` or `Parent` instances. Any class that has `Parent` in it's inheritance hierarchy could be passed then.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method using the type of the Parent, and it will work with both

```
void DoSomething(Parent parent)
{
}
```